# Pandas working with 2D array inside dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, data-structures

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing a 2D array as a column looking something like the following:

```
Name    2DValueList
item 1  [ [ 0.0, 1.0 ], [ 0.0, 6.0 ], [ 0.0, 2.0 ] ]
item 2  [ [ 0.0, 2.0 ], [ 0.0, 1.0 ], [ 0.0, 1.0 ] ]
item 3  [ [ 0.0, 1.0 ], [ 0.0, 3.0 ], [ 0.0, 5.0 ], [ 0.0, 1.0 ] ]
item 4  
item 5  [ [ 0.0, 4.0 ], [ 0.0, 1.0 ], [ 0.0, 2.0 ] ]
```

The first value isn't relative to this question so I've just made them all 0. I'm only interested in the second values. Also notice the amount of pairs can vary or be empty.

**I want to be able to make a new dataframe that just contains the top    (largest) *n* elements from the array.**

It would look like this for the top 2 elements:

```
Name    2DValueList
item 1  [ [ 0.0, 6.0 ], [ 0.0, 2.0 ] ]
item 2  [ [ 0.0, 2.0 ], [ 0.0, 1.0 ] ]
item 3  [ [ 0.0, 5.0 ], [ 0.0, 3.0 ] ]
item 4
item 5  [ [ 0.0, 4.0 ], [ 0.0, 2.0 ] ]
```

I would use pandas nlargest, but I'm not sure how to make it accept a column that is a 2D array.

In reality, the 2D array holds thousands of value pairs and there are tens of thousands of rows. I'm open to better ways to hold this data that would be more versatile.

Comment: Has each element of 2DValueList the same number of elements? Or could each 2D array have its own individual number of pairs?

Comment: each row will have a varying number of pairs if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

If every cell of `2DValueList` is list of lists, the efficient way is using `heapq.nlargest` with `itemgetter` together with list comprehension

```
from heapq import nlargest
from operator import itemgetter

df['new_list'] = [nlargest(2, x, key=itemgetter(1)) for x in df['2DValueList']]

Out[119]:
     Name               2DValueList            new_list
0  item 1  [[0, 1], [0, 6], [0, 2]]    [[0, 6], [0, 2]]
1  item 2  [[0, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1]]    [[0, 2], [0, 1]]
2  item 3  [[0, 1], [0, 3], [0, 5]]    [[0, 5], [0, 3]]
3  item 4  [[0, 4], [0, 1], [0, 2]]    [[0, 4], [0, 2]]
```

If each cell is a numpy 2darray, the above method still works fine. However, I think using numpy `argsort` would be better

```
df['new_list'] = [x[np.argsort(-x, axis=0)[:2,1]] for x in df['2DValueList']]

Out[128]:
     Name               2DValueList            new_list
0  item 1  [[0, 1], [0, 6], [0, 2]]    [[0, 6], [0, 2]]
1  item 2  [[0, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1]]    [[0, 2], [0, 1]]
2  item 3  [[0, 1], [0, 3], [0, 5]]    [[0, 5], [0, 3]]
3  item 4  [[0, 4], [0, 1], [0, 2]]    [[0, 4], [0, 2]]
```

Lastly, if you don't need the top n largest sub-array in sorted order, `argpartition` would be faster than `argsort`

Comment: Each cell is a list of lists, so i'll try your first method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast

df['2DValueList'] = df['2DValueList'].apply(ast.literal_eval).apply(lambda x: sorted(x,reverse=True)[:2])
```

---

```
     Name       2DValueList
0  item 1  [[0, 6], [0, 2]]
1  item 2  [[0, 2], [0, 1]]
2  item 3  [[0, 5], [0, 3]]
3  item 4  [[0, 4], [0, 2]]
```